# parsing a file and build a query

Tags: shell

I have a file which contains

```
CF=test1
HOST=kp10
USER=user1
PASSWORD=password1
CF=test2
HOST=kp11
USER=user2
PASSWORD=password2
```

I want to build  query by parsing the file .i.e grep each 4 lines and take out the value

```
insert into x=test1 ,host=kp10,user=user1,password=password1
insert into x=test2 ,host=kp11,user=user2,password=password2
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: awk -F'=' '/=/ {print $2}' myfile .I don't know shell script so not able to proceed

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy:

```
$ cat file | paste -d, - - - - | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' | sed 's|.*|insert into &|'
insert into cf=test1,host=kp10,user=user1,password=password1
insert into cf=test2,host=kp11,user=user2,password=password2
```

Step by step:

1. `cat` passes file's content to `paste`
2. `paste` joins each 4 lines together and use comma as separator
3. `tr` converts from upper case to lower case
4. `sed` prepends string 'insert into ' to each line